# Group Policy on Win8.1 in WAN Environment won't fully apply

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-8.1

Client computer is Win 8.1 with local DHCP server/subnet and network based VPN (WAN) to the main server. DNS is set to the main server, on which client is registering itself correctly. Client can correctly access all network resources including SYSVOL with \domain.local\Sysvol

Some Group Policies are completing, but not all of them, particularly not the Software Installation policy.

Error in Event Log is:

> Event ID 1030 
>   The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows attempted
>   to retrieve new Group Policy settings for this user or computer. Look
>   in the details tab for error code and description. Windows will
>   automatically retry this operation at the next refresh cycle.
>   Computers joined to the domain must have proper name resolution and
>   network connectivity to a domain controller for discovery of new Group
>   Policy objects and settings. An event will be logged when Group Policy
>   is successful.

There's nothing decipherable in the XML

GPResult.exe on the client computer gives the same error, informs:  A fast link was detected, and reports: Software Installation did not complete policy processing because a system restart is required for the settings to be applied. Group Policy will attempt to apply the settings the next time the computer is restarted.

No number of restarts is going to fix this issue.

Wait for network before processing GP is Enabled in the Domain Wide Policies.

I've tried forcing slow connection detection off, and process Software Installation Policy Enabled on Slow Connections with no effect.

There are no MSIEXEC log events.

Except for the above error, GPRESULT on the client specifically documents it's going to run the Software Installation Policy.

I've tried turning on Group Policy Trace Logs and nothing is generated, although its possible that GP is not being processed and I need to turn it on locally.

This is happening on two 'just imaged' vanilla Win 8.1 machines at the same site that only has a DHCP server, no DC.

Two other sites with DCs are both applying all Group Policies correctly. DC replication is working properly.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: `No number of restarts is going to fix this issue.` - But have you actually tried restarting?

Comment: Echo logonserver to be sures that the correct DC that answer, as the site is surelly not in ad site and service. the dclocator service can forward the request some where else. Thus can fall depending of the rule of the tunnel.

Comment: @joeqwerty it's been restarted many dozens of times already.

Comment: @yagmoth555 good idea, but %logonserver% is correct.

Comment: Magically started working a week later when I reboot all the servers for scheduled maintenance. Bloomin' hell.